# what disk format I better choose for my windows server 2016 virtual machines for clustering?

Tags: hyper-v, cluster, windows-server-2016, windows-cluster, cluster-shared-volumes

I want to create 3 virtual machines hosted on my computer windows 10.

these 3 machines would be :

1) 1 machine to be used as a domain controller

2) 2 machines running windows server 2016 datacentre `or` standard edition

I have some questions.

the first question is which one of the disk formats I need to choose in order to add drivers to my cluster (after I create the cluster)

[image: the choose disk format picture]

Comment: The first problem is that you want to run the VMs on Windows 10. For proper supported virtualization you need a server OS as the hypervisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends,

I mean if you want implement a File sharing server in cluster some of the disk have to be shared between the VMs so for that disk the only choice is *VHD set* which is designed for this purpose.

If sharing disk is not necessary I'm suggesting you to use VHD which (as per the description in the image) seems more stable then VHDX which provide up to 64TB (but for a test environment i think go up to 2 TB are enough good.